# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Tor Stack Exchange](http://tor.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why does GnuPG show the signature of Erinn Clark as not trusted?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/why-does-gnupg-show-the-signature-of-erinn-clark-as-not-trusted)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Entry guards are persistent for a period of time when using Tor. How is it done?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/entry-guards-are-persistent-for-a-period-of-time-when-using-tor-how-is-it-done)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [If I am an exit node can/should I restrict certain sites?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/if-i-am-an-exit-node-can-should-i-restrict-certain-sites)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it possible to create a Tor Hidden Service in Python (Django) or Ruby (Rails)?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/is-it-possible-to-create-a-tor-hidden-service-in-python-django-or-ruby-rails)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can Tails be installed as primary OS?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/can-tails-be-installed-as-primary-os)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Got a Trojan with Tor download](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/got-a-trojan-with-tor-download)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [my Atlas page is blank](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/my-atlas-page-is-blank)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Site login does not persist](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/site-login-does-not-persist)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why sometimes Atlas shows different IP address than https://check.torproject.org?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/why-sometimes-atlas-shows-different-ip-address-than-https-check-torproject-org)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to validate certificates?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-validate-certificates)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---